# Send data using GET method not work correctly

Tags: multisite

Im using WP 3.5.2 and WPMU. I develop one page http://baohiem.info/chon-mat-gui-vang.
This page uses global $wpdb to query table _blogs.(_blogs was customized, added some fields.)
When submit form, I use GET method, but, when log in, i have data ($_REQUEST; $_GET) but not log in, there're no data.
Why? I don't understand what happen.
Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

```php
<?php
get_header(); 
?>

        <form action="" method="get">
            <input id="searchfield-cmgv" type="text" name="hoten" placeholder="Họ và tên tư vấn viên...." size="35" value="<?=$_REQUEST['hoten']?>"/>
            <!-- location-->
            <select name="location">
                <option value="">-------- Tỉnh/TP --------</option>
                <option value="Hà Nội" <?php if($_REQUEST['location']=='Hà Nội') echo 'selected';?> >Hà Nội</option>
                <option value="TP Hồ Chí Minh" <?php if($_REQUEST['location']=='TP Hồ Chí Minh') echo 'selected';?> >TP Hồ Chí Minh</option>
                <!-- <option value="Huế" <?php if($_REQUEST['location']=='Huế') echo 'selected';?> >Huế</option>-->
                <option value="Đà Nẵng" <?php if($_REQUEST['location']=='Đà Nẵng') echo 'selected';?> >Đà Nẵng</option>
                <option value="Hải Phòng" <?php if($_REQUEST['location']=='Hải Phòng') echo 'selected';?> >Hải Phòng</option>
                <option value="Đồng Nai" <?php if($_REQUEST['location']=='Đồng Nai') echo 'selected';?> >Đồng Nai</option>
                <!-- <option value="Đồng Tháp">Đồng Tháp</option>
                <option value="Gia Lai">Gia Lai</option> -->
                <option value="Hà Giang" <?php if($_REQUEST['location']=='Hà Giang') echo 'selected';?> >Hà Giang</option>
                <!-- <option value="Hà Nam">Hà Nam</option>
                <option value="Hà Tĩnh">Hà Tĩnh</option> -->
                <option value="Hải Dương" <?php if($_REQUEST['location']=='Hải Dương') echo 'selected';?> >Hải Dương</option>
                <option value="Nghệ An" <?php if($_REQUEST['location']=='Nghệ An') echo 'selected';?> >Nghệ An</option>
                <option value="Thái Nguyên" <?php if($_REQUEST['location']=='Thái Nguyên') echo 'selected';?> >Thái Nguyên</option>
                <option value="Yên Bái" <?php if($_REQUEST['location']=='Yên Bái') echo 'selected';?> >Yên Bái</option>

           </select>
           <select name="company">
               <option value="">-------- Công ty --------</option>
               <option value="Prudential" <?php if($_REQUEST['company']=='Prudential') echo 'selected';?> >Prudential</option>
               <option value="Manulife" <?php if($_REQUEST['company']=='Manulife') echo 'selected';?> >Manulife</option>
               <option value="AIA" <?php if($_REQUEST['company']=='AIA') echo 'selected';?> >AIA</option>
               <option value="Dai-ichi Life" <?php if($_REQUEST['company']=='Dai-ichi Life') echo 'selected';?> >Dai-ichi Life</option>
               <option value="ACE Life" <?php if($_REQUEST['company']=='ACE Life') echo 'selected';?> >ACE Life</option>
               <option value="Bảo Việt" <?php if($_REQUEST['company']=='Bảo Việt') echo 'selected';?> >Bảo Việt</option>
               <option value="Hanwha Life" <?php if($_REQUEST['company']=='Hanwha Life') echo 'selected';?> >Hanwha Life</option>
               <option value="Generali" <?php if($_REQUEST['company']=='Generali') echo 'selected';?> >Generali</option>
               <option value="Chưa có" <?php if($_REQUEST['company']=='Chưa có') echo 'selected';?> >Chưa có</option>
           </select>
            <input type="hidden" value="true" name="confirm" />
           <input id="searchbutton" value="Tìm kiếm" type="submit">
        </form>
        
           <?php
           global $wpdb;

            // lấy thông tin công ty, họ tên, location
            $company = $_GET['company'];
            $hoten = $_GET['hoten'];
            $location = $_GET['location'];

        if(!$company && !$hoten && !$location){

                // string query
                $strquery = '
                                        SELECT bh_blogs.blog_id
                                        FROM bh_blogs
                                        WHERE bh_blogs.blog_id >1
                                        AND bh_blogs.deleted =0
                                        ORDER BY bh_blogs.voted DESC        
                ';

                // get result
                $res = $wpdb->query($strquery);

                // display result
                //
                //
        } else {
           //var_dump($location); var_dump($company); var_dump($hoten);
            $strquery = '
                SELECT bh_blogs.blog_id
                FROM bh_blogs
                WHERE bh_blogs.blog_id > 1 AND bh_blogs.deleted =0 ';

            if($hoten!='') $strquery .= ' AND bh_blogs.site_name LIKE "%'.$hoten.'%" ';
            if($company!='') $strquery .= ' AND bh_blogs.company="'.$company.'" ';
            if($location!='') $strquery .= ' AND bh_blogs.location="'.$location.'" ';

            $strquery .= ' ORDER BY bh_blogs.voted DESC ';

            //display result
            //
            //
        }  

    get_footer(); 
?>
```

the url: [http://baohiem.info/chon-mat-gui-vang/?hoten=&location=Hải+Phòng&company=Prudential](http://baohiem.info/chon-mat-gui-vang/?hoten=&location=H%E1%BA%A3i+Ph%C3%B2ng&company=Prudential) not work.
I can't Get['location'],Get['hoten'],Get['company']

---

Resolved:
I use the plugin Better WP Security and it filters my URL.

To enable passing parameters like: example.com?src=SomeSource&page=1.....
Log in to you ACP. Better WP Security/System Tweak and uncheck the option "Filter Suspicious Query Strings".

Note: attention with your parameters is safe for your site :)

Merry Christmas.

Comment: Can you post your code here, what did you try?

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer rather than an edit. Answers can be upvoted and marked as the correct answer. The site still thinks you haven't found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear. What exact information are you trying to obtain and can you post a code example?
The login information is set via a cookie so perhaps this is what you're looking for?
It's only used for /wp-admin/ and it's hashed so this might not work for your example.

See here for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies

Comment: I comment my code above. Pls show me what problem?

Comment: I thought you were trying to access user login information so my answer is irrelevant here

Comment: No, i want get the params for string query. But don't receive data.
When i loged, this link http://baohiem.info/chon-mat-gui-vang/?hoten=&location=Hải+Phòng&company=Prudential WORK($_GET['location'].... are true.).  But not log, It doesn't.

Comment: oh, my problem is resolved. I use plugin Better WP Security, and it filters my URL.

Thank you for your support.